# Non holomorphic Siegel-Poincare series growth

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, siegel-modular-forms

Let $H_g$ be the Siegel upper-half plance of genus $g$, and $\Gamma=Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$ the full modular group of genus $g$. As usual, we can define non-holomorphic Eisenstein and Poincare series as
$$E^{(g)}_k(Z,s)=\sum_\gamma \delta(\gamma Z)^s j(\gamma,Z)^{-k}$$
$$P^{(g)}_{A,k}(Z,s)=\sum_\gamma \delta(\gamma Z)^s j(\gamma,Z)^{-k}e^{2\pi i \sigma(A\gamma Z)}$$
where $\delta(Z)=\det(\Im(Z))$, $j(\gamma,Z)=\det(C_\gamma Z+D_\gamma)$, $A$ a half-integral positive semidefinite symmetric matrix, $\sigma$ is the trace and the sum is over $\Gamma_{g,0}\backslash\Gamma_g$, for $\gamma\in\Gamma_{g,0}\iff C_\gamma=0$.

> Is $P^{(g)}_{A,k}(Z,s)$ decreasing exponentially fast for $\Im(Z)$ "going up", for any $A>0$?

To explain what "going up" means, think of $g=1$ and fix $s=0$: then we know that $P^{(1)}_{A,k}(Z,0)$ is a cusp form for any $A\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and, like every cusp form, decreases exponentially fast for $\Im(Z)\to\infty$. For higher genus $g>1$, I think the "height" of $Z$ should be $\delta(Z).$

So, when $s=0$, the answer to my question is *yes* for any genus. I think the same should be true for any $s$ such that the series are nicely convergent (so for $\Re(s)\ge$ some negative quantity depending on $k$ and $g$), because of the exponential factors in the definition: in fact,
$$P^{(g)}_{A,k}(Z,s)=\delta(Z)^s e^{2\pi i\sigma(AZ)}+\sum_{\gamma\not=I} \delta(\gamma Z)^s j(\gamma,Z)^{-k}e^{2\pi i \sigma(A\gamma Z)}$$
so my wishful thinking here suggests that the dominant term "going up" is the first exponential summand, and the remaining part is irrelevant.

But, by taking absolute values on that series, we see that it is majorated by
$$\delta(Z)^{-k/2}\delta(Z)^{s+k/2}\sum_{\gamma\not=I} |j(\gamma,Z)|^{-k-2s}=\delta(Z)^{-k/2}\left(E^{(g)}_{0}(Z,s+k/2)-\delta(Z)^{s+k/2}\right)$$
and the last factor is known to behave polynomially: hence, this approach does not tell us that the remaining part of the Poincare series is irrelevant; on the other hand, the exact same reasoning applies for $s=0$ where we do know the result is true.

Any idea/result to shed some light here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, it turns out that the notion(s) of "height" in higher-rank groups should be as follows: in Iwasawa coordinates $nmk$ with $n$ in the unipotent radical of a minimal parabolic, $m$ in a Levi-Malcev component, and $k$ in a maximal compact, the "heights" are $\chi(m)$ as $\chi$ runs through (multiplicative) simple roots. So the number of different "directions" to infinity is in general greater than one.

Second, the case of holomorphic Poincare' series is somewhat anomalous, since they are indeed genuine cuspforms, but only due to considerable cancellation. Without cancellation, the terms with lower and lower heights do not decay uniformly very-rapidly, and so their sum is not uniformly of rapid decay.

Comment: Yeah I came to the same conclusion, that the exponential decay is due to cancellation that does not happen when considering absolute values. On the other hand, can anything be said for the non-holomorphic Poincare series at $s\not=0$? Ideally, when $s$ is _small_, the impact of the added factor is small as well, so not much should change overall(?)